# Problemas con bindParam() PHP | Consulta MySQL Dinámica

Tags: php, mysql, count

quiero pedirles su apoyo para resolver un problema con una consulta dinámica para contar los registros que cumplan una o varias condicione.

Esta consulta se ejecuta sin ningún problema, pero no me da el resultado correcto, las condiciones WHERE pueden variar de tipo 'NOT IN' o 'IN', ejemplo WHERE color NOT IN (:color0, :color1, :color2), espero explicarme bien, mi código es el siguiente:

```
$classGeneral = new generalQuery(DATABASE_SERVER.ERP_BASE);
/* Contamos cuantos registros existen en total */
$whereCount = array(
              'color' => array('rojo, verde', 'NOT IN', 'string'),
              );
$totalRecords = $classGeneral->countRecords('tabla_Productos', $innerJoin, $whereCount);

// El método de mi clase
public function countRecords($table_Select, $innerJoin_Select = array(), $where_Select = array()){
    $this->tableSql = $table_Select;
    $this->whereSql = $where_Select;
    $this->valueSql;

    try {
        $this->statmentSql = 'SELECT count(*) as numRecords FROM '.$this->tableSql;

        #### Este es el código parcial de mi clase, exactamente donde tengo el problema, antes de esto solo construye la consulta, lo cual lo hace muy bien.

        $this->cnxServer->beginTransaction();
        $countSql = $this->cnxServer->prepare($this->statmentSql);


       /* Si pruebo creando estáticos los bindParam, así, me funciona muy bien, cuenta los registros con sus condiciones de forma correcta
       $a1 = 'rojo';
       $a2 = 'verde';
       $countSql->bindParam(':color0', $a1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $countSql->bindParam(':color1', $a2, PDO::PARAM_STR);*/


      // Creamos los bindParam dinámicos a través del array, que es aqui donde me interesa funcione
      foreach($this->whereSql as $key => $value) {
          if(strcmp(array_values($value)[1], 'IN') === 0 OR strcmp(array_values($value)[1], 'NOT IN') === 0){
               $valueIn = explode(',', array_values($value)[0]);
               $longitud = count($valueIn);
               $valBind = '';

               //AQUI ES DONDE HE DETECTADO EL PROBLEMA
               for($a = 0; $a < $longitud; $a++) {
                    $valBind .= trim($valueIn[$a]);
                    $countSql->bindParam(':'.$key.$a, $valBind, (strcmp(array_values($value)[2], 'string') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_STR : PDO::PARAM_INT);
               }
          } elseif(strcmp(array_values($value)[1], 'WHERE') === 0 || strcmp(array_values($value)[1], 'NOT') === 0){
               $valBind = trim(array_values($value)[0]);
               $countSql->bindParam(':'.$key, $valBind, (strcmp(array_values($value)[2], 'string') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_STR : PDO::PARAM_INT);
          }
     }       
        
     if(!$countSql->execute()){
          print_r($countSql->errorInfo());
     } else {
          $this->cnxServer->commit();
          $numCountItems = $countSql->fetch();
          $this->valueSql = $numCountItems['numRecords'];
     }

     return $this->valueSql;
      
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $this->cnxServer->rollBack();
         echo "Failed count records: " . $e->getMessage()."<br />";
     }
}
```

Alguna sugerencia o corrección?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les dejo la solución, únicamente debí cambiar el bindParam por un bindValue en el ciclo for, con esto enlaza el valor que inserto sin problema y me da el resultado correcto de mi consulta

```
for($a = 0; $a < $longitud; $a++) {
      $valBind .= trim($valueIn[$a]);
      $countSql->bindValue(':'.$key.$a, $valBind, (strcmp(array_values($value)[2], 'string') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_STR : PDO::PARAM_INT);
           }
```